# c program assign an int to a bool?

Tags: c, int, boolean

I'm programming a mcu. This is the description of the `gpio_read_pin()` function. It returns a bool.

Can I assign this to an `int ack`? and test if ack is a 0 or 1?

Thanks

```
/**
 * Read the current value of a single pin on a given GPIO port.
 *
 * @param[in] gpio GPIO port index.
 * @param[in] pin Pin of GPIO port to read.
 * @return bool Value of the pin specified on GPIO port.
 */
bool gpio_read_pin(const gpio_t gpio, const uint8_t pin);



void sendCommandSHT(int command)
{

  ...

  int ack;

  ack = gpio_read_pin(QM_GPIO_0, DATA_PIN);

  if (ack != 0) {
      TI_PUTS("Ack Error 0");
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it seems kinda...  pointless?

Comment: Yes, you can assign an integer value to an integer variable. Just make sure the value fits into the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can assign an `int` value to a `bool` object. Both are integer types, and the value is implicitly converted.

Old versions of C, prior to 1999, did not have a built-in Boolean type. It was common to use workarounds such as;

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

or

```
#define false 0
#define true 1
typedef int bool;
```

For such a type, the behavior of the conversion depends on just how the Boolean type is defined. If `bool` is an alias for `int`, the conversion is trivial. If the value being converted is exactly `0` or `1`, the result is `false` or `true`, respectively. If the value is anything else, you can get a value that is neither `false` nor `true`, but that will be treated as true when used as a condition (but *not* when compared for equality to `true` -- so don't do that). You can even get an unspecified value that might be `0` for a non-zero `int` value (for example if `bool` is defined as `char` and the high-order bits are discarded).

If you're not able to use modern C, either because you have a pre-C99 compiler or because you're working on legacy code, you can normalize the value:

```
int n = 42;
bool b = (n == 0 ? false : true);
```

or

```
bool b = n != 0
```

or

```
bool b = !!n;
```

C99 added a built-in type `_Bool`, which can be written as `bool` if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`. Conversion to `_Bool` automatically normalizes the value. Conversion of an `int` to type `_Bool` yields `0` (`false`) if the value is equal to zero, `1` (`true`) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Original `C` doesn't really have a `bool` type. However, it's usually defined as:

`typedef enum { false = 0, true = 1 } bool;`

> Can I assign this to an int ack? and test if ack is a 0 or 1?

So for your Q - yes.

---

In C99 `bool` type exists, using `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: C very well **does** have a boolean type! And the `enum` is a strict don't. Use `stdbool.h`.

Comment: @Olaf it's not before C99, editted

Comment: If not mentioned otherwise, a question is about standard C. Which is currently C11. Read the info-page. And `bool` is a macro for the actual name of the type.

Comment: C99 has no **bool**, just **_Bool**

Comment: "but needed check for C99 or C11" - Please update your language knowledge before writing an answer. C has evolved in the past 27 years. K&R is not even C89.

Comment: @atturri - `bool` is ok, it's macro resolved to `_Bool`. I don't really see people use `_Bool` directly - can be wrong though

Comment: @atturri: 1) address a comment properly. As I suspect you mean me: I did not state it has a `bool`, but a **boolean type**. `stdbool.h` provides `bool` as a macro for `_Bool`, though. Note the standard made redefinition of this and the `true`/`false` macros obsolesecence, which might very well be an indicator a future standard might make them keywords.

Comment: true, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Olaf: "*K&R is not even C89.*" That depends on what you mean by K&R.  "K*R C" usually refers to the language described by the first edition of Kernighan & Ritchie (K&R1), published in 1978. The second edition, K&R2, described the language defined by the 1989 ANSI and 1990 ISO C standards.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Common understanding of "K&R-C" is the pre-standard version. Later versions are typically called "ANSI-C" (C89 == C90), or "ISO-C" (ambivalent, as C is an ISO standard since C90). But no way is K&R standard C, as no edition of the book covers C99, even less the only valid standard version C11.

Comment: Are you disagreeing with anything I wrote? The older standard are *officially* obsolete; each standard "cancels and replaces" the previous edition. But the older standards still exist, and it's absurd IMHO to say that they're not "standards". They are standards, just not current ones. It's reasonable to say that a compiler conforms to the 1990 ISO C standard, for example; how would you say that?